# How to modify Trigger to update a single attribute in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Here is my sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_test(
idTst SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
monthDownload VARCHAR(6),
changeDate DATE);
```

I am trying to create a function and trigger that would update changeDate attribute with a current date when monthDownload attribute is updated. 
The function I have it works with one problem. It updates all records instead of the one that was updated.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION downloadMonthChange() 
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
 $$
 BEGIN
 IF NEW.monthDownload <> OLD.monthDownload THEN
 UPDATE employee_test
 SET changeDate = current_date
 where OLD.idTst = NEW.idTst;
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$ 
 Language plpgsql;
```

Trigger

```
Create TRIGGER dataTest
AFTER UPDATE
ON employee_test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE downloadMonthChange();
```

When I execute the following Update statement:

```
UPDATE  employee_test SET  monthDownload = 'oct12'
WHERE idTst = 1;
```

> All changeDate rows get update with a current date. 
>   Is there a way to have only a row with changed record to have a current date updated.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `before` trigger you can write directly to `NEW`

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION downloadMonthChange() 
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
 $$
 BEGIN
 IF NEW.monthDownload <> OLD.monthDownload THEN
   NEW.changeDate = current_date;
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$ 
 Language plpgsql;
```

the other option when you must use an `after` trigger is to include the primary key in the `where` clause. It appears that you were trying to do this, but you had a spurious `OLD` in the query. beause of that the where clause was only looking at the record responsible for the trigger call, and not limiting which records were to be updated.

```
 IF NEW.monthDownload <> OLD.monthDownload THEN
 UPDATE employee_test
 SET changeDate = current_date
 where idTst = NEW.idTst;
```